# Can't insert query (java and mysql)

Tags: java, mysql, wamp

I just can't find the mistake, i get the error: `Erreur de syntaxe près de '?, ?)' à la ligne 1`.

It's looks like my DB can't understand the query code.

```
    public void inserir(){

    String sql = "INSERT INTO funcionarios (nome, funcao) values (?, ?)";
    //verificação de erros

    try {

        //os ?? da query sera substituido pelo conteudo das variaveis

        pst = conexao.prepareStatement(sql);

        pst.setString(1, txtnome.getName());
        pst.setString(2, txtfunc.getText());    

        //executa a query
        pst.executeUpdate(sql);


        conexao.close();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Funcionário adicionado ao banco de dados!");

    } catch (Exception e) {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro: " + e);
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Can I get some help?

Comment: print query to the console and check how it is forming

Comment: Is it possible that you created your table with back quotes? If so try using your query as `"INSERT INTO \`funcionarios\` (\`nome\`, \`funcao\`) values (?, ?)"`

Comment: I've tried with those back quotes and nothing, on console, works fine with `"INSERT INTO funcionarios (nome, funcao) values ('blabla', 'blalba')"`